# SharePoint filtered column that only allows item to be used once

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have a WSS 3.0 site that I use for change management. There are three primary lists on it -- a bug list, an enhancement list, and a release list. The release list has two lookup columns that provide a list of bugs and enhancements that are included in that particular release.

I am trying to figure out how to filter the bug and enhancement list to include only items that have not already been included in another release. All the docs and examples I have seen regarding filtered lookups deal with a query on the list itself. For my situation, and if this was a SQL query, I would need to use a LEFT JOIN to generate the list.

Answer (score 1):

To use SharePoint lists something like relational tables, you should try out [SLAM](http://slam.codeplex.com/) (SharePoint list association manager), that is just what you need for this situation.

After you've set up your relations, you will then have a database you can use to query and determine if value has been used or not within your custom filtered lookup field.